# Roblox for Linux not working

Tags: linux, roblox

I know that Roblox is made for Windows, but I didn't want to spend time installing it on my PC that already runs Linux perfectly fine. I did some research and found that I needed to install something called Grapejuice (for Wine) to run Roblox. It's installed and everything, but I still can't play.

If I try to launch from the browser, it just throws the "You're almost ready to play, install Roblox here" junk.

If I launch the installed app, it loads, but when I try to log in, it tells me "an unexpected error occurred, try again later."

What did I do wrong?

---

Note: I don't currently have access to my PC right now, so I can't provide any commands, files, or computer specifications; I also don't remember the site I visited to install Grapejuice.

Comment: Did you register URL handlers?

Comment: @RayWu what exactly does that mean?

Comment: Paging in one year later. It's likely that your browser required a restart to register the new handlers for Grapejuice to identify and launch the player with.

Answer (score -3):

Like you said, Roblox is made for Windows. It is not supposed to run on systems it is not supposed to. Emulation layers like Wine is very basic and are going to throw errors at you when the target application tries to access parts of Windows that Wine does not offer, which in this case Roblox is probably trying to locate and connect to a Windows system module that is non-existent in a emulation by Wine or any other emulators. My suggestion would be that if you do not want Windows to be on your pc, just play Roblox on your phone or console. Otherwise, a virtual machine would be the closest you can get to playing Roblox on Linux although the performance would very much be garbage like the 20 fps I am seeing when playing a game called "Easy Obby" from a Windows 10 VirtualBox machine on Pop!_OS.

Comment: I don't care about the FPS; I care about actually having the game working. If I didn't want to have Roblox on my PC I wouldn't have asked this question. I already have Roblox on my phone and it's not that good because you can't control vehicles. Also, I never play obbys so I don't have to worry about lag.

Comment: Additionally, I'm not just using Wine, I installed Grapejuice because that was made specifically for Roblox to be played on Linux. I'm not asking to get answers that say "Oh you can't because it's not made for it" because people have made programs that enable it to be compatible.

Comment: Please read this link: https://devforum.roblox.com/t/grapejuice-easily-run-roblox-on-linux/262949